# Выбор данных по условию из DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data[  ((data.price < 2) & (data.price > 0)) 
     | (data.price > 10) 
     & (data.prime_genre == 'Games') 
     & (data.prime_genre == 'Shopping')
]
```

Почему не выбираются столбцы `Games` и `Shopping`?

Comment: data.price = столбец с ценой

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__не картинкой__) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

условие `(data.prime_genre == 'Games') & (data.prime_genre == 'Shopping')` - противоречиво! Значение не может быть одновременно и `'Games'` и `'Shopping'`.

попробуйте так:

```
data.query("(0 < price < 2  or  price > 10) and prime_genre in ['Games', 'Shopping']")
```

Comment: огромное спасибо! все работает!